# Numbering Chapters and header issue

Tags: formatting, numbering, fancyhdr

I am a complete newbie to latex so I apologise if the questions asked are straightforward, I am using the document class with fancyhd, with a documentclass of report. However when producing my report I am getting the following:
[image: not numbered]

The chapters aren't numbered and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction to firstly number them and secondly reduce the space between the chapter heading and the title, below is my awful ever changing main tex file:

```
    %Loading in the packages
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm ,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[acronym, toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\restylefloat{table} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{\mkbibbold{\mknumalph{#1}}}

\graphicspath{{images/}}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\lstset{
    basicstyle = \footnotesize\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    xleftmargin=1cm,
    xrightmargin=\parindent,
}

%Loading in the pagestyling
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyhead[LO, CE]{Section \thesection}
\fancyfoot[LO, CE]{test format}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

% Redefine the plain page style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyhead[LO, CE]{Section \thesection}
\fancyfoot[LO, CE]{test format}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
}

\begin{document}

%\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
%\input{chapters/Acknowledgements}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\chapter{chapter1}

\chapter{chapter2}

\chapter{chapter3}

\chapter{chapter4}


\end{document}
```

I also have another issue, on pages such as the contents page I am getting the following, chapter 0, I wish to simply remove the heading if possible and just keep the line. I hope this makes sense apologies for my awful formatting and please help :-/
[image]

Comment: The chapters *are* numbered, in both of your images, and when I try your example on my machine. By the way, don't load packages unless you actually need them.

Comment: I mean I would like it to appear 1.Introduction